# Android - Blank fragment when returning from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed, fragment-backstack

I have a view that shows a List of Properties, at the bottom of the screen there's a button that opens a fragment containing a MapView.

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.find_property_btn_map:

            PropertyMapFragment fragment = PropertyMapFragment.newInstance(false, null);

            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(), fragment, PropertyMapFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();

            break;
    }
}
```

The onCreateView method for my Properties fragments is as follows

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_properties_list, container, false);
    getmBtnMap().setOnClickListener(this);
    getmBtnSaveSearch().setOnClickListener(this);
    getmBtnSort().setOnClickListener(this);
    getmListView().setAdapter(getPropertyAdapter());
    getmListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    getmListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    getmListView().setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

    searchProperties();

    return mRootView;
}
```

`searchProperties();` takes care of calling a Web Service and filling the `ArrayAdapter`.

The thing is that, when I open the `MapFragment` and then press the back button, my `Property fragment` is blank and the buttons do not respond to `onClick` events.

I tried debugging and saw that `onCreateView()` is being called when coming back to `Property fragment`, but the buttons are no longer working and the `listview` is nowhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId()` when you show `PropertyMapFragment`? If not, I'd suggest to replace that for `R.id.container`:   `.replace(R.id.container, fragment, PropertyMapFragment.class.getSimpleName())`

Comment: Yes, I use it like that because I'm calling it inside the property fragment, not inside the containing activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to launch that web view from a fragment, then try to use add fragment instead of **replace**.

**For example :**

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(YOUR_CONTAINER_ID, fragment, PropertyMapFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
```

The code above is replace that fragment container with the new one and not adding that fragment on top of that. So when you do a replace fragment with that **ID**, it just replaces that view with new one.

Now,

**Same code but with add:**

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(YOUR_CONTAINER_ID, fragment, PropertyMapFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
```

Now, that web view fragment that you have will be added to the view/fragment and now when you press back from that web view, you previous fragment will be visible.

Just make sure that that the **ID** you are replacing is the same as the one in which you have all the other properties.

Maybe i misinterpreted the question so please correct me in that context.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mike20132013, I tried changing `replace()` for `add()` but `onResume()` is never called with this approach and I need the UI to update when the user returns to Properties fragment.

Comment: That's right. In this case, onResume will not be called cause its just on the stack. But if you do need to call the onResume(), You can host 2 fragment's with one activity right and control onResume state that way. In that way, you won't loose your data either.

Answer (score 1):

addToBackStack() <--dont include this for your first fragment.-->

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() !=1){
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
```